# How do I add nested categories to a Django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

What I am trying to achieve is to design a model which has nested levels of categories.

the levels are like this.

`category0 > category1 > category2 > category3 > category4 > category5`

Posts can have levels from `0 - 5`, so a post can have category `0 - 1`, while other post may have`0 - 4` or `0 - 5`,

The category on the given highest level (`0` is the lower while `5` is the highest) should inherit from the one just below it, (`1 > 2 > 3 > 4 > 5`)

How can I achive this?

My current categories looks like this

```
class Category0(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=60)


class Category1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=60)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Category0)


class Category2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=60)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Category1)


class Category3(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=60)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Category2)


class Category4(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=60)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Category3)


class Category5(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=60)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Category4)
```

And the post model here

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    slug = AutoSlugField(unique=True, populate_from='title')
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(CategoryChild4)
```

What would be the best method? any suggestions or changes welcome.

**Update**

The backend is PostgrSQL.

Thanks

Comment: have a look at [django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Could you use a `Foreign Key` to `self` approach?

For example:

```
class Category(models.Model):

    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', default=None, null=True, blank=True, related_name='nested_category')
    nesting_level = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=60)
```

It's probably useful to keep track of the nesting levels explicitly with `nesting_level` but this way you can create the relationship you describe.

Answer (score -4):

If you are using Postgres as your database, I probably would not take this approach. I would look into using the new json datatype (postgres 9.3>). If you want to utilize this you can store this type of information in document form (think mongo-db but in an RDBMS). I recommend installing this field:

https://github.com/bradjasper/django-jsonfield/

The only downside is that you need to perform validation yourself, but since this a multiple layered model, you would probably need to do that anyway based on the way you are doing it above.

You could look into using MongoDB also....

Comment: why would you advise to look at a non-rel database model without knowing the project's details, or any database backend at all? If all the op needs is a parent-child hierarchy your direction is nonsense, this is possible with any backend and quite common

Comment: okay about dumping json, but can I get all the objects belonging to a specific category? (say `category3`) ?